# how can i read data from a file then edit it and print it in the same file?

Tags: c

What I'm trying to do is read this text from a file:

> Tomorrow, and tomorrow, and tomorrow,
>   Creeps in this petty pace from day to day,
>   To the last syllable of recorded time;
>   And all our yesterdays have lighted fools
>   The way to dusty death. Out, out, brief candle!
>   Life's but a walking shadow, a poor player
>   That struts and frets his hour upon the stage
>   And then is heard no more. It is a tale
>   Told by an idiot, full of sound and fury
>   Signifying nothing.

And change it all to upper case letters.

I can do this if I read the text from one file and print to another.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <ctype.h>
int main() {
    FILE* input_file = fopen("some_text.txt", "a+");

    char c = fgetc(input_file);
    int charc = 0;
    int alpha = 0;
    while(1){
        if(isalpha(c)){
            alpha = alpha + 1;
        }
        charc = charc + 1;

        fprintf(input_file,"%c",toupper(c));
        c = fgetc(input_file);

        if(feof(input_file)){
            break;
        }
    }
    fprintf(input_file,"\nTotal Characters: %d, Total alphabetical characters: %d",charc,alpha);

    fclose(input_file);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: You do not want to edit a file in-place with C. (you can, but you can not change the length of the file - dicey at best). Instead open a file for reading and one for writing. Read from your read file, make any changes to the data and write it back out to your write file. Then delete the read file and move the write file back to the original read file name. Also better to just `while ((c = fgetc (input_file)) != EOF) { ... }` (simply changing `toupper(c)` and writing back would work, but you have to manipulate your file-position carefully)

Comment: Personally, the best way to handle this case is just to get the file size, declare a buffer to hold the entire file, open the file for reading, use `fread()` to read the entire file into the buffer at once, close the file, loop over each char in buffer doing `buffer[i] = toupper(buffer[i]);` and then open the file for writing and write the entire buffer back out with a single call to `fwrite()`.

Comment: @DavidRankin-ReinstateMonica Your second comment is definitely the most direct way to do this. You should post it as an answer...

Answer (score 2):

If you are simply wanting to convert all characters in a file to uppercase and write the results back to the same file, the direct approach is to open the file for reading, get the length of the file and allocate a buffer to hold the entire file and read the entire file into the buffer, and close the file. Then loop over each character in the buffer calling `toupper()` on each character and converting the buffer to all uppercase. Then open the file again for writing which will truncate the file and then write the entire buffer back out to the file closing the file and freeing the buffer when you are done.

A short example taking the filename to convert as the first argument could be:

**Open File in `"r"` (Read) Mode**

```
...
int main (int argc, char **argv) {

    char *filebuf = NULL;
    long fplen = 0;
    FILE *fp = NULL;

    if (argc < 2) { /* validate argument given for filename */
        fprintf (stderr, "usage: %s filename\n", argv[0]);
        return 1;
    }

    if (!(fp = fopen (argv[1], "r"))) { /* open/validate file open for read */
        perror ("fopen-read");
        return 1;
    }
```

**Determine File Length**

```
    fseek (fp, 0, SEEK_END);            /* seek end of file */
    if ((fplen = ftell (fp)) == -1) {   /* get file length */
        perror ("ftell-length");
        return 1;
    }
    fseek (fp, 0, SEEK_SET);            /* seek beginning */
```

**Allocate Storage for `filebuf`**

```
    /* allocate memory for file */
    if (!(filebuf = malloc (fplen * sizeof *filebuf))) {
        perror ("malloc-filebuf");
        return 1;
    }
```

**Read Entire File Into `filebuf` & Close File**

```
    /* read file into filebuf */
    if (fread (filebuf, 1, fplen, fp) != (size_t)fplen) {
        perror ("fread-filebuf");
        return 1;
    }
    fclose (fp);                        /* close file after read */
```

**Convert `filebuf` to UpperCase**

```
    for (long i = 0; i < fplen; i++)    /* convert all chars toupper */
        filebuf[i] = toupper(filebuf[i]);
```

**Open File for Writing `"w"` Mode & Write `filebuf` to File & Close**

```
    if (!(fp = fopen (argv[1], "w"))) { /* open/validate file open for write */
        perror ("fopen-write");
        return 1;
    }
    /* write filebuf to file */
    if (fwrite (filebuf, 1, fplen, fp) != (size_t)fplen) {
        perror ("fwrite-filebuf");
        return 1;
    }

    if (fclose (fp) == EOF)             /* validate close-after-write */
        perror ("fclose_after-write");
```

(**note:** you always validate *close-after-write* to catch any error associated with flushing the stream that would not be caught on your validation of `fwrite`)

**Free `filebuf` Memory**

```
    free (filebuf);
```

That is it in a nutshell. Putting it altogether you could do:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <ctype.h>
#include <limits.h>

int main (int argc, char **argv) {

    char *filebuf = NULL;
    long fplen = 0;
    FILE *fp = NULL;

    if (argc < 2) { /* validate argument given for filename */
        fprintf (stderr, "usage: %s filename\n", argv[0]);
        return 1;
    }

    if (!(fp = fopen (argv[1], "r"))) { /* open/validate file open for read */
        perror ("fopen-read");
        return 1;
    }

    fseek (fp, 0, SEEK_END);            /* seek end of file */
    if ((fplen = ftell (fp)) == -1) {   /* get file length */
        perror ("ftell-length");
        return 1;
    }
    fseek (fp, 0, SEEK_SET);            /* seek beginning */

    /* allocate memory for file */
    if (!(filebuf = malloc (fplen * sizeof *filebuf))) {
        perror ("malloc-filebuf");
        return 1;
    }
    /* read file into filebuf */
    if (fread (filebuf, 1, fplen, fp) != (size_t)fplen) {
        perror ("fread-filebuf");
        return 1;
    }
    fclose (fp);                        /* close file after read */

    for (long i = 0; i < fplen; i++)    /* convert all chars toupper */
        filebuf[i] = toupper(filebuf[i]);

    if (!(fp = fopen (argv[1], "w"))) { /* open/validate file open for write */
        perror ("fopen-write");
        return 1;
    }
    /* write filebuf to file */
    if (fwrite (filebuf, 1, fplen, fp) != (size_t)fplen) {
        perror ("fwrite-filebuf");
        return 1;
    }

    if (fclose (fp) == EOF)             /* validate close-after-write */
        perror ("fclose_after-write");

    free (filebuf);
}
```

**Example Input File**

```
$ cat dat/cj2upper.txt
This is a tale
Of Captain Jack Sparrow
A Pirate So Brave
On the Seven Seas.
```

**Example Use**

```
$ ./bin/fread_file_toupper dat/cj2upper.txt
```

**Resulting Output File**

```
$ cat dat/cj2upper.txt
THIS IS A TALE
OF CAPTAIN JACK SPARROW
A PIRATE SO BRAVE
ON THE SEVEN SEAS.
```

Look things over and let me know if you have questions. There is more than one way to do this, but this is likely one of the more direct routes.

Comment: Note that on Windows, fread  is likely return fewer bytes vs. what fseek reports (since each CRLF is convered to '\n').

Comment: @dash-o Yes, good point, but with an explicit `size_t size` parameter set to `1` that should eliminate the multi-byte character issue (and basically makes `toupper()` have to handle the pieces which may be an issue). UTF-16 introduces a number of cases.

Answer (score 0):

Almost right, here are some changes to make it work 
First open the file in binary mode, this allows you to move in the file with fseek. the rb+ means you can read/write to the file.
Added some error handling if file is not there, always have error handling.
When you write back to the disk, make sure to flush it out to disk since fgetc et al work on a buffer.
fputc is better in this case, since you are anyway just writing one char.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <ctype.h>
int main() 
{
  char filename[] = "some_text.txt";
  FILE* input_file = fopen(filename, "rb+"); // open in binary mode
  if ( input_file == NULL ) // some error handling
  {
    perror(filename);
    return -1;
  }

  int c = fgetc(input_file); // return value is int
  int charc = 0;
  int alpha = 0;

  do
  {
    if(isalpha(c))
    {
      alpha = alpha + 1;
    }
    charc = charc + 1;

    // if alpha, then go back one character and rewrite it
    if(isalpha(c)) 
    {
      fseek(input_file, -1, SEEK_CUR);
      fputc(toupper(c),input_file); // use fputc instead of fprintf
      fflush(input_file);
    }
    // read next
    c = fgetc(input_file);
  }
  while (c != EOF);

  // at end of file, add some more
  fprintf(input_file,"\nTotal Characters: %d, Total alphabetical characters: %d",charc,alpha);

  fclose(input_file);
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: For efficiency, consider changing the condition for update to 'if ( islower(c))'. It will avoid update on characters already in uppercase.

Answer (score 0):

For performance reason, assuming that most characters will need conversion, make sense to leverage STDIO, which will leverage application level buffering

Example eliminate error checking for readability.

```
main(...)
{
   // Open file
   FILE *fp = ... ;
   const int BUFFER_SIZE = 1024 ;
   char buff[BUFFER_SIZE] ;

   while ( 1 ) {
       // Read
       long loc = ftell(fp) ;
       n = fread(buff, 1, sizeof(buff), fp) ;
       if ( n <= 0 ) break ;

       // Convert
       int do_update = 0 ;
       for (int i=0 ; i<n; i++ ) {
           if ( islower(buff[i] ) {
              buff[i] = toupper(buff[i]) 
              do_update = 1 ;
           } ;
           if(isalpha(c)){
               alpha = alpha + 1;
           }
           charc = charc + 1;
        } ;

        // Update, only if anything changed
        if ( do_update ) {
            long next = ftell(fp) ;
            fseek(fp, loc, SEEK_SET) ;
            fwrite(buff, 1, n, fp) ;
            fseek(fp, next, SEEK_SET) ;
        } ;
   } ;
}
```